# Cannot find Math.net in References after installing package with NuGet in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, math, visual-studio-2015, package

I'm trying to use the Math.net extension for Visual Studio 2015 with C#.

Unfortunately, after installing the package with

`PM> Install-Package MathNet.Numerics -Version 3.20.0`

I cannot find it anywhere in the Add References menu. I searched Assemblies->Framework and Assemblies->Extensions and COM, but it's not there

I wouldn't mind the just adding the DLL to my project, but I cannot find the DLL anywhere on https://numerics.mathdotnet.com , all the links take me to the NuGet package manager.

Also, do I need to distribute the MathNet dll with my application if I add it through the package manager, or does it build internally with the application?

Sorry, new to .net library management

Comment: I see that I can do a manual download of the .nupkg file and open it with 7Zip to find a couple of 100mb dlls. Which must not be the right build.

Answer (score 0):

I see that when I ran the command line, it added a `packages` folder to my project folder. Which has a few different versions of the library per .net version. Which I could browse to with Add Reference->Browse->Browse

Is this the correct way about adding a third party library?